# How do you plot geo-encoded locations on a custom map?

Tags: google-maps, maps, geocoding, geo

I have a number of events in the US. I have addresses for these events, but it varies in accuracy. Some might be the full address, some might be just "Austin, Texas".

I'd like to plot these programatically on a map on a webpage with a marker as they'll change fairly regularly. The marker should be an internal link to the relevant row in the table of events lower down on the page.

The image doesn't need to be updated on the fly, just on the (say fortnightly occasions) when an event is added (e.g. a cached image is cleared and recreated)

Rather than use Google maps, I'd like to plot these on top of an image like this: http://0.tqn.com/d/geography/1/0/9/H/usa3.jpg

How would I go about putting markers on this image that correspond to the (rough) geolocation of these events?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to use google maps and plot the locations and then just pull an image of the map - that way you can let google do all the work of placing the pins but not have to worry about people zooming, since it is a static image file.

Beyond that, you can type the locations into any mapping service to get a rough idea of the location and then place markers or dots on your map file in the same location. This would allow you to choose whatever image or color you want the icons/markers to be, since you will find and place them yourself.

Comment: I've clarified my question, but yes, one one of the requirements is that they should be plotted programatically as the events will change/be added to by other admin users on a fairly regular basis.

Comment: Can you further clarify your question? Is this for a website, application, etc? Does it need to be dynamic or just able to generate a new (static) image file when you add/remove pins? You haven't given much information.

Comment: Tried clarifying again, sorry. In short: on a website, just need to regenerate a static image every week or two rather than people adding a marker on the fly etc.